# Android - xml text views not filling parent correctly

Tags: xml, layout, android-layout, textbox, spinner

Whats up stackoverflow.  I am trying to make my android xml layout look as professional as possible, but as of right now it feels very amature(probably because im new at app development), would anybody be able to help get my text box's width to fill the parent correctly?  and if you have any pointers please let me know?  THANK YOU!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.11"
    android:background="@drawable/repeat"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Setup New Account"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Please enter a password below"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="174dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="237dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="174dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Re-Enter"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="237dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Select a Security Question"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="288dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="174dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Answer"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />




            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="174dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Re-Enter"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="237dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had trouble because i was using the wrong layout, and that was causing me to have trouble sizing my buttons and widgets to the screen

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more clear with what you are trying to accomplish. Is this a web application? What language/platform are you working with? Do you have a code sample you can share?

Comment: sorry this is an android application. and this is in java, my xml file

Answer (score 0):

For filling the parent completely, you should use

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```